# Подсчет повторяющих елементов в массиве php

Tags: массивы, php

Здраствуйте.
Есть код допустим

```
<?php
$list=array("q"=>"bla bla","result"=>array());
$list["result"][]=array("type"=>"movie","title"=>"ahaha");
$list["result"][]=array("type"=>"movie","title"=>"ahaha");
$list["result"][]=array("title"=>"blblblbl");

?>
```

Как подсчитать количество в массиве $list["result"] записей с type "movie"
Узнавать через for или fosearch ненадо. (очень часто надо будет проверять).
Если есть уже стандартная функция то просьба подсказать.
Спасибо.

Comment: @BIcolStresh, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: как я понимаю данные из БД. может проще модифицировать запрос? или добавить еще один.

Comment: Несовсем, даные парсятся. Знаносятся в массив и потом отдаю json.

Answer (score 2):

А чем Вам не нравится циклический перебор? Думаете стандартная функция будет как-то по другому считать?
Если массив динамически меняется во время работы программы, и нагрузка при пересчете количества вхождений велика, то можно сделать так

```
function addMovie(name){
    global $list, $entries;
    $list['result'][]=name
    $entries+=1;
};
```

Не спорю, есть функция [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php), но она создаст еще большую нагрузку.

Answer (score 2):

```
$count = array_reduce($list["result"], function($l, $r) { 
    return $l + (isset($r["type"]) && $r["type"] == "movie" ? 1 : 0); 
}, 0);
```

Если PHP < 5.3, то вместо анонимной функции нужно использовать обычную, разумеется.

> очень часто надо будет проверять

В таких случаях код просто выносится в функцию.

Comment: "type" может содержать один с 8 вариантов (я в том что не только "movie").
Можете написать функцию?

Comment: @BicolStresh это тот же foreach, только с вызовом функции для каждого элемента массива. Не прельщайтесь насчет скорости.

Comment: > "type" может содержать один с 8 вариантов (я в том что не только "movie").

Вместо `$r["type"] == "movie"` используйте что-то вроде `in_array($r["type"], array("movie", "foo", "bar"))`


> @BicolStresh это тот же foreach, только с вызовом функции для каждого элемента массива. Не прельщайтесь насчет скорости.

В скорости сколько-нибудь большой разницы не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальная функция для подсчета элементов в массиве - `array_count_values ();`

```
$array = array (1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values ($array));
```

**Результат:**

```
Array

(

    [1] => 2

    [hello] => 2

    [world] => 1

)
```

Comment: А если подсчет производиться часто - можно заврапить вызовы этой функции в простой класс и там кешировать ответ

Comment: Насколько мне известно, `array_count_values()` считает элементы первого уровня, а в вопросе автора искомые элементы находятся в `$list['result][*переменная*]['type']`, так что в поставленой задаче работать не должно.

Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.